# Redux Form - Checkbox with a default value and set it to be disabled

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, redux, redux-form

I'd like to confirm if this structure is right.

I need to set default value for the checkbox, so I've used the checked={input.value}. I also need to set it to be disabled, then I've passed the disabled prop:

```
// Using the Checkbox component  
<Field
  name="completed"
  label="Completed"
  disabled={this.props.disableCompleted}
  component={Checkbox}
/>

function Checkbox({ input, label, disabled }) {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="mt-checkbox">
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          disabled={disabled} 
          checked={input.value} 
          {...input} /> {label}
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The value of a checkbox input is typically not the "checked" state of the checkbox, so this seems odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation for enabling/disabling a checkbox is correct.

For displaying the default checked value for a checkbox you'll need to use `defaultChecked`. In your example, you're not passing down a `input` value to `Checkbox` (I see only `disabled` and `label`). Make sure you are and that it's a boolean value. Then you should be good to go.